# Rivescript en servidor hosting no funciona

Tags: php, composer, inteligencia-artificial

Estoy tratando de ejecutar una IA con rivescript en mi servidor de hosting. Ejecuté el composer para instalar rivescript localmente y luego cargar los archivos en mi servidor de hosting. Todo iba bien hasta que al ejecutar los archivos, en especial el archivo .rive, no funciona. Debería devolver una respuesta a mi archivo text.txt pero no puedo. ¿Alguien ha hecho algo similar? muchas gracias. Aqui el codigo de mi index.php:

```
    <?php
//DESHABILITAMOS EL MOSTRAR ERRORES
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 0);
error_reporting(-1);

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
//IMPORTAMOS LAS LIBRERIRAS DE Rivescript
use \Axiom\Rivescript\Rivescript;

/*
 * VERIFICACION DEL WEBHOOK
*/
//TOQUEN QUE QUERRAMOS PONER 
$token = 'AgentId';
//RETO QUE RECIBIREMOS DE FACEBOOK
$palabraReto = $_GET['hub_challenge'];
//TOQUEN DE VERIFICACION QUE RECIBIREMOS DE FACEBOOK
$tokenVerificacion = $_GET['hub_verify_token'];
//SI EL TOKEN QUE GENERAMOS ES EL MISMO QUE NOS ENVIA FACEBOOK RETORNAMOS EL RETO PARA VALIDAR QUE SOMOS NOSOTROS
if ($token === $tokenVerificacion) {
    echo $palabraReto;
    exit;
}

/*
 * RECEPCION DE MENSAJES
 */
//LEEMOS LOS DATOS ENVIADOS POR WHATSAPP
$respuesta = file_get_contents("php://input");
//CONVERTIMOS EL JSON EN ARRAY DE PHP
$respuesta = json_decode($respuesta, true);
//EXTRAEMOS EL MENSAJE DEL ARRAY
$mensaje=$respuesta['entry'][0]['changes'][0]['value']['messages'][0]['text']['body'];
//EXTRAEMOS EL TELEFONO DEL ARRAY
$telefonoCliente=$respuesta['entry'][0]['changes'][0]['value']['messages'][0]['from'];
//EXTRAEMOS EL ID DE WHATSAPP DEL ARRAY
$id=$respuesta['entry'][0]['changes'][0]['value']['messages'][0]['id'];
//EXTRAEMOS EL TIEMPO DE WHATSAPP DEL ARRAY
$timestamp=$respuesta['entry'][0]['changes'][0]['value']['messages'][0]['timestamp'];
//SI HAY UN MENSAJE
if($mensaje!=null){
    //file_put_contents("text.txt", $mensaje);

  //INICIALIZAMOS RIVESCRIPT Y CARGAMOS LA CONVERSACION
    $rivescript = new Rivescript();
    $rivescript->load('ChatIA.rive');
    //OBTENEMOS LA RESPUESTA
    $respuesta= $rivescript->reply($mensaje);
    //ESCRIBIMOS LA RESPUESTA
    file_put_contents("text.txt", $respuesta);
}
```

aqui estas los archivos de mi servidor:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]